# How would I go about building a model for item selection?

Tags: regression, predictive-models

I have 8000 items. They've each been rated on a scale from 1-7.

I have ~40 non-mutually exclusive dichotomous properties for each item.

I build a regression model with those 40 as predictors of the ratings. My goal is to find the predictors that are most predictive of ratings, and then based on those, choose the 10 items that should be rated highest and lowest.

I've tried stepwise regression, LASSO, random forests and best subsets regression.

Is there any approach out there that would be better?

Comment: Can you clarify what aspects of the models you tried left you unsatisfied?

Comment: Hi @JohnMadden. They have a very low R2. I know that may just be a product of the data, but I wanted to see if any other approaches would be better.

Comment: oh, then it sounds like the problem you're running into is somewhat orthogonal to the variable selection stuff, so maybe we had ought to split this analysis into two parts: 1) are there any models which give reasonable performance, even *in sample*, i.e. can anything, even a neural net/other flexible predictor give us a high R2? and 2) can we find a subset of variables that preserves this performance?

Comment: Sounds good! Would you be able to point me to some ways to tackle #1 in R?

Comment: ah well, this is the entire problem of *regression analysis*: for general nonlinear models, I would start with neural nets (I believe there's an R version of keras), xgboost, and I'd try a linear model with interaction terms (there's about 800 coefs in total, may want to try regularization). BTW: it seems like you're treating your ratings as a continuous scale, as opposed to an ordinal one?

Comment: Okay I will look into those! In terms of the model with interactions. Would I just take the LASSO I am running now, but include all main effects as well as two way interactions?

Comment: I think that's a great place to start, yes.